# How to stretch line between two cells (<td> tags)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to stretch a line between two cells.
I have table with cells and I want to stretch line from one cell to another cell.

This is what I have:
[image]

This is what I **want**:
[image]

I tried to use `<canvas>` tag according to [HTML canvas lineTo() Method](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/canvas_lineto.asp) but it didn't work.
I tried to add it before and after the table's tag without success.
Maybe someone knows how to do it.
I added jsfiddle example: [JSFIDDLE example](http://jsfiddle.net/1zrw5ro2/)

**CSS:**

```
td {
    width: 100px;
    height: 90px;
    text-align: left;
    vertical-align: top;
    border: 1px solid black;
    position: relative;
}
table
{
    position: fixed;
    left:9px;
    top:8px;
}
tr:nth-child(even) td:nth-child(odd), tr:nth-child(odd) td:nth-child(even)
{
    background:#00A2E8;
}

.soldiers
{
    width:20px;
    height:20px;
    position: absolute;
}

td span {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<body>

<div id="board" value="5">

<table oncontextmenu="return false">
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td class="" cellnumber="21" row="4" col="0"><span>21</span></td>
        <td class="" cellnumber="22" row="4" col="1"><span>22</span>
            <br><br><p class="SnakesAndLadders" from="22" to="6">Snake to 6 </p></td>
            <td class="" cellnumber="23" row="4" col="2"><span>23</span></td>
            <td class="" cellnumber="24" row="4" col="3"><span>24</span></td>
            <td class="" cellnumber="25" row="4" col="4"><span>25</span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td class="" cellnumber="16" row="3" col="0"><span>16</span></td>
            <td class="" cellnumber="17" row="3" col="1"><span>17</span></td>
            <td class="" cellnumber="18" row="3" col="2"><span>18</span></td>
            <td class="" cellnumber="19" row="3" col="3"><span>19</span></td>
            <td class="" cellnumber="20" row="3" col="4"><span>20</span></td></tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="" cellnumber="11" row="2" col="0"><span>11</span></td>
                <td class="" cellnumber="12" row="2" col="1"><span>12</span></td>
                <td class="" cellnumber="13" row="2" col="2"><span>13</span></td>
                <td class="" cellnumber="14" row="2" col="3"><span>14</span></td>
                <td class="" cellnumber="15" row="2" col="4"><span>15</span>
          <br><br><p class="SnakesAndLadders" from="15" to="24">Ladder to 24 </p>
              </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="" cellnumber="6" row="1" col="0"><span>6</span></td>
                        <td class="" cellnumber="7" row="1" col="1"><span>7</span></td>
                        <td class="" cellnumber="8" row="1" col="2"><span>8</span></td>
                        <td class="" cellnumber="9" row="1" col="3"><span>9</span></td>
                        <td class="" cellnumber="10" row="1" col="4"><span>10</span></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="" cellnumber="1" row="0" col="0"><span>1</span></td>
                        <td class="" cellnumber="2" row="0" col="1"><span>2</span></td>
                        <td class="" cellnumber="3" row="0" col="2"><span>3</span></td>
                        <td class="" cellnumber="4" row="0" col="3"><span>4</span></td>
                        <td class="" cellnumber="5" row="0" col="4"><span>5</span></td>
                    </tr>
```

Comment: There's no JavaScript code in the jsfiddle you linked. How exactly did your `<canvas>` attempt not work?

Comment: @Pointy, I added a clean example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[check the fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/La292q67/)

```
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="600" height="500"></canvas>
<script>
  var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
  var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

  context.beginPath();
  context.moveTo(350, 50);
  context.lineTo(450, 350);
  context.stroke();
</script>
```

CSS

```
#myCanvas {
    z-index: 10;
    position:absolute;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a simple `div` element, with a black border, and rotate it using css `transform`. Then, position it absolutely where you want with `top` and `left` properties:

```
.line {
    position: absolute;
    height: 200px;
    -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
    border: 2px solid black;

    top: 50px;
    left: 300px;
}
```

[**Updated Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/1zrw5ro2/1/)